# Need some help on creating sym links

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

Using Linux Centos 6

I have 16 years of data sorted in directories by year and then day (1997/001, 1997/002...).  Each 'day' directory has 24 files, 1 for each hour, with hour name in each file (i.e. `1997.001.00.bin`, `1997.001.01.bin`...`1997.001.23.bin`).

I can't change the filename or the algorithm used to name the files.  I have a script that reads the meta data in the file and archives it into the correct year/day directory.  However, the first file of each day actually begins at 23:59:59.  So that first file of each day actually gets archived on the previous day. `1997.001.00.bin` actually gets archived in `1996/365` directory.

I need to generate symlinks so that the a link for `1997.001.00.bin` resides in `1997/001` and points to the actual location in `1996/365`.  If it were only a few files, I'd just run the command by hand, but I need to do this for 5000+ files.  Any help on generating some commands for a script would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the file correctly named? I mean is the first file of `1997` actually `1996/365/1997.001.00.bin`? Or is it `1996/365/1996.001.00.bin` or something?

Answer (score 3):

Run this in the directory that holds 2012, 2013, etc.

```
find * -type f -name "*bin" -exec sh -c 'ln -s ../../{} `echo {} | sed -r '\''s,.*/([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+).*,\1/\2,'\''`' \;
```

It finds *bin files that are regular files, not symlinks, and creates a symlink for each of them in the right directory. It can be run multiple times without issue, say after new *bin files are created, though you will get errors like `ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘2013/002/2013.002.00.bin’: File exists`. These can be ignored.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Your command will run things like `ln -s ../../1996/067/1996.067.19.bin 1996/067`. 1) The file `../../1996/067/1996.067.19.bin` will never exist, why the `../../`? 2) You are linking _all_ files, not just the one in the wrong directory. 3) Even if you did get part 1) right, you still would be linking the same file to itself, your `sed` command is just printing the same year and day as in the original file name.

Comment: 1) That is the string put into the symlink, which is in one of the month directories, so yes, `../../1996/067/1996.067.19.bin` does exist. 2) It will just fail with `File exists` for ones in the right directory.  3) When files are in the wrong directory, it creates a symlink to them in the right directory. If the second parameter to ln is a directory, it will create the symlink in that directory, using the basename of the reference.

Comment: @teardon: I tested this before posting, and can guarantee that it works.

Comment: So did I and it didn't :). Add an `echo` to the beginning of the `exec` and you'll see. It will print out a long list of commands like the example I gave in my previous comment. As you can see there, you are not changing directories, even if you are right about the `../../` and I still don't see why you think so, it would still be pointing to a directory of the same name. As far as I an tell, the OP needs to link `1996/365/1997.001.00.bin` to `1997/001/1997.001.00.bin` and you are linking `../../1996/365/1997.001.00.bin` to `1996/365/1997.001.00.bin`.

Comment: We aren't changing directories. The symlink itself needs to contain `../../`, he needs a symlink `1996/365/1997.001.00.bin` that contains `../../1997/001/1997.001.00.bin`, which is what this command does.

Comment: It's very late here and I am falling asleep so I may be missing something obvious but I still don't see how you get `1997/001/` from `1996/365/`. Your `sed` command does not do that: `sh -c 'echo "1996/365/" | sed -r '\''s,.*/([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+).*,\1/\2,'\'''` returns `1996/365/`.

Comment: The sed is being fed filenames, not directory names. So it takes `1996/365/1997.001.00.bin` and spits out `1997/001` Note the .*/ in the `sed` expression. The greedy .* combined with the / matches the directory component, which we throw away. We don't care what directory they are already in, only where they should be.

Comment: My most profound apologies, you are absolutely correct and I'm being an idiot. Serves me right for trying to answer just before bed. Not only does yours work, mine does not as you correctly pointed out. OK, downvote removed upvote added and I'm off to bed to forget my sorrows .

Comment: Thanks for the upvote terdon :) It's been a stimulating discussion at least. Sleep well.

Answer (score 0):

If the mis-archived file is correctly named, this should work (just paste it into a terminal in the parent directory):

```
nxtyear="";
tmrow="";
for year in $(seq 2012 -1 1996); do 
 for day in $(seq -f "%03g" 365 -1 1); do 
  [ -d $year/$tmrow ] && 
  ln -s ../../$year/$day/$nxtyear.$tmrow.00.bin $nxtyear/$tmrow/;
  tmrow=$day;
  nxtyear=$year;
 done; 
done
```

This assumes that the first file of 1997 is at `1996/365/1997.001.00.bin`. In other words, that it is correctly named but incorrectly placed. If this is not the case, let me know and I'll modify my answer.

---

#### Explanation

The little script above will cycle through every year from 2012 to 1996 backwards, and likewise for all numbers from 365 to 001. At the end of its loop, it saves the current day as `$tmrow` and the current year as `$nxtyear`. The first time it runs, these will be undefined and the script will do nothing (that's why I'm checking if the directory exists with `[ -d $year/$tmrow ] &&`).

Every time the script loops, it will link a file called  `$year/$day/$nxtyear.$tmrow.00.bin` to `$nxtyear/$tmrow/`. So, for example, when `$year` is `1996`, and `$day` is `365`, `$nxtyear` will be `1997` and `$tmrow` will be `001`. The script will therefore run

```
 ln -s 1996/365/1997.001.00.bin 1997/001/
```

You can check what the script will do without having it make any changes by adding `echo` to the `ln` line:

```
[ -d $year/$tmrow ] && 
echo ln -s $year/$day/$nxtyear.$tmrow.00.bin $nxtyear/$tmrow/;
```

Comment: This script doesn't work: the symlinks it creates cannot be followed. See our comments in my answer, you need to include a `../../` in your symlinks. Try doing a `cat` on one of the symlinks and you can see it goes nowhere.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner no it doesn't, you're right again. It should work now, but I'll test tomorrow.